# "next generation of" or "next generation"?

Tags: phrases

What would be the correct way of saying "X is the next generation of Hockey stand"?

Some possibilities I thought of:

"X is the next generation Hockey stand"
"X is the next generation of Hockey stands"

Comment: Both can be grammatical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are fine, provided you hyphenate *next generation* in the first one:

[1] *X is the next-generation Hockey stand.*

On the other hand,

[2] *X is the next generation of Hockey stand*

is not fine.

**Discussion**

**1. The complement of the preposition *of***

In the construction

*the next generation of Y*

*Y* is normally either a plural count noun (*the next generation of **leaders***) or an uncount noun (*the next generation of **research***). Singular count nouns are possible, but are much more rare and, as best as I can tell, they are always marked as indefinite by *a/an* (*use this equipment to introduce the next generation of **a product that complements an existing product line**; anatomic structures necessary for the birth of the next generation of **a given species***). So, *the next generation of **a hockey stand*** is possible if there are are several lines of hockey stands, i.e. several models of hockey stands, and we are discussing the next generation of any of those models.

But I don't think it is acceptable for Y to be a bare (i.e. one with no article in front of it) singular count noun phrase, which is the case in [2].

**2. Hyphenation**

If a noun (or a compound noun such as *hockey stand*) is modified by an adjective+noun combination that appears before it, we need to put a hyphen between the adjective and the noun (see e.g. p. 3 [here](https://at.bi.no/EN/Documents/ChicagoManualofStyleHyphenationChartch07_tab01.pdf)):

> *small-state* senators
>   a *high-quality* alkylate
>   a *middle-class* neighborhood

However, if the adjective+noun combination appears after the noun, then we leave it open:

> the neighborhood is *middle class*

**3. Capitalization**

I am not clear on what a *Hockey stand* is, and so am unsure if it really needs to be capitalized. However, unless it is some sort of a brand name, or if *Hockey* is a person's name, then it probably should **not** be capitalized.

Comment: The original "X is the next-generation of hockey stand" is not correct, right?

Comment: That's right. There's no justification for the hyphen there.

Comment: I meant the "of". so is "X is the next generation of hockey stand" correct?

Comment: Oh yeah, I missed that. Right. In the construction *the next generation of Y*, Y  is normally either a plural count noun (*the next generation of **leaders***) or an uncount noun (*the next generation of **research***). Singular count nouns are possible, but are much more rare and, as best as I can tell, they are always marked as indefinite by *a/an* (*use this equipment to introduce the next generation of **a product that complements an existing product line***; *anatomic structures necessary for the birth of the next generation of **a given species***).

Comment: *The next generation of **a hockey stand*** is possible if there are are several lines of hockey stands, i.e. several models of hockey stands, and we are discussing the next generation of any of those models.

Comment: Also, thanks for accepting the answer, but let me just note that it's usually a good idea to give it a day or two (at least) before accepting **any** answers. You can certainly upvote in the meantime, but it's a good idea to allow sufficient time to hear multiple points of view—as well as sufficient time for discussion if there are disagreements.

Comment: For example, you can see that I have already significantly expanded my answer as a result of this short exchange with you. Don't jump the gun on accepting an answer. True, you can change your mind later and un-accept it (or accept a different answer), but the fact you've already accepted an answer may discourage others from providing alternative points of view.